# how to upload file in dropzone using python code automatically

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, automation, dropzone

I am trying to write a code to submit a webform with python code. I am using selenium which is a great library. It works well with normal elements.
For dropzones, I am unable to find a solution. Dropzones are not input elements which makes it difficult to upload files to them using selenium.

I am specifically looking at the following webform:
https://gnps-quickstart.ucsd.edu/featurebasednetworking

There are few dropzones at the bottom. The second one doesn't seem to be connected with any hidden input field.

Any idea or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time;

web = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe');

web.get('https://gnps-quickstart.ucsd.edu/');

time.sleep(2);

optional_email_field = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]');

email_id = 'email@domain.edu';

optional_email_field.send_keys(email_id);

mgf_field = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div')

mgf_file = 'nov_10_1.mgf';

mgf_field.send_keys(mgf_file);

form_submit_field = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="analyzebutton"]');
time.sleep(3)
form_submit_field.click();
```

Comment: Can you provide your code trails?

Comment: Turns out that the dropzones does not upload the files. Files are still uploaded through input fields. In my case input field was hidden but I was able to access it with code which did the job for me.